# Applying the integral identity for reciprocal of the difference of squares sqrted

Tags: integration

Here are two attempts to the same problem:

Solution 1:
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{4-9w^2}} &= \int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{2^2 - (3w)^2}}\\
&= \color{red}{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3w}{2}\right) + C}\color{grey}{\quad\gets\quad\text{by }\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{a^2 - u^2}} = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac ua\right) + C}
\end{aligned}
Solution 2:
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{4 - 9w^2}} &= \int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{\frac14\left(1 - \frac94w^2\right)}}\\
&= \frac12\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{1 - \frac94w^2}}\\
&= \frac12\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{1^2 - \left(\frac32w\right)^2}}\\
&= \frac12\left(\frac23\right)\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1^2 - u^2}}\quad\gets\quad\color{grey}{\require{bbox} \bbox[2pt,border:1px solid grey]{\begin{matrix}u = \frac32w\\ du = \frac32dw\implies dw = \frac23du\end{matrix}}}\\
&= \frac13\sin^{-1}\left(u\right) + C\color{grey}{\quad\gets\quad\text{by }\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{a^2 - u^2}} = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac ua\right) + C}\\
&= \color{green}{\frac13\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3w}2\right) + C}
\end{aligned}

According to [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite/Prob16.aspx), the solution in green above is correct. Why is the use of that integral identity in grey not legitimate when applied directly before factoring stuff out from the integrand's denominator?

Obviously the two solutions are not equal, so I'm assuming mine is invalid, unless it is possible for a function to have two antiderivatives, set aside the infinite possible values of $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into similar problems in further calculations with other identities, I figured out what I was doing wrong.

In the solution with the red answer in the original question, no variable substitution was performed before applying the identity, so the application of the identity will not work because the variable term $w$ doesn't have a coefficient of one. To fix this, one can either rearrange the integral expression to make the coefficient of $w$ one, or perform variable substitution, as follows:

\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{4-9w^2}} &= \int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{2^2-(3w)^2}} = \frac13\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{2^2 - u^2}}\quad\left(\text{where \( u = 3w \implies \frac{du}{3} = dw \)}\right)\\
&=\frac13\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right) = \color{red}{\frac13\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3w}2\right)}
\end{aligned}

Now the answer in red (the one directly above in this answer) is correct, because variable substitution was performed as a prerequisite for applying the provided identity. I would argue that this solution is a little cleaner than the one used to come to the green answer in the original question, because it avoids having to take the square root of a quotient, eliminating two steps from the overall process.

Answer (score 1):

The red answer is incorrect because the gray identity is itself stated incorrectly: it should be
$$
\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{a^2 - u^2}} = \color{blue}{\frac1a} \, \sin^{-1}\left(\frac ua\right) + C.
$$

Comment: There was a mistake in the basic integral identities sheet that I memorised. Not my lucky week. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm… Just realised it might have not been a mistake. A quick search for "table of integrals" on the web shows a lot of tables that all have "my version" of that integral identity in them (without the 1/a reciprocal before the arcsin term). Would someone know why that is?

Comment: Besides, I think your solution would still not work, because it would yield a coefficient of one half rather than a third. Could you double-check that?